# Questions on how to ssh into a remote server on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ssh, port, ubuntu-18.04, portforwarding, forwarding

I'm a beginner in this sort of thing so I could use a bit of help.

I'm usually able to ssh into my school's local cluster using the following command in Ubuntu 18.05 LTS

`ssh username@hostname.com`

Now this only works when I'm connected to my school's wifi. Whenever I'm off of it, I receive the following error.

`ssh: connect to host hostname.com port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable`

After some online digging, I figured I needed to port forward into the server, so I tried putting `-L 22:localhost:22` after `ssh`, but it gave me the following error:

`Privileged ports can only be forwarded by root.`

If I put `sudo` before everything, it gives me the same port 22 error from before. I'm terribly lost and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is off-topic at StackOverflow. if you can connect to remote port 22 directly then ```-L XXX:localhost:22``` mapping does not make any sense. such port forwarding makes sense when remote port is bound to 127.0.0.1 and thus is not accessible directly. If you want to connect another server on the "camp" internal network then you could use port mapping like -L 2222:ip-address-of-second-server:22 while connecting to the gate (so you connect to the gate to construct/setup mapping and _then_ you could connect to such second/internal server via ```ssh me@localhost -p 2222```)

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should ask questions like this on [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], or [su].